# Javascript / ajax refuses to display XML data

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I'm absolutely stumped by what is going on right now and it's incredibly frustrating because I've done this many times of the passed few weeks without error. But suddenly now, displaying XML data in an HTML page using JavaScript has somehow become impossible. Let me explain.

I'm working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. I have created several web pages over the passed few weeks (as ASP.NET projects and .aspx files instead of .html). This time, instead of creating an .aspx file, I've created an .html file that you can see below. Please note i've put the CSS and JavaScript inline so it's easier to read:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

      <style type = "text/css">
         h2 {color:Navy}

         li 
         {    
             font-family : monospace;
             font-weight: bold; 
             color:Navy;
         }

         li:hover {color: red;}
      </style>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "stylesheets/stocks.xml",
                  dataType: "xml",
                  success: function (xml) {
                      $(xml).find('Stock').each(function () {
                          var company = $(this).find('Company').text();
                          var market = $(this).find('Market').text();
                          var sector = $(this).find('Sector').text();
                          var price = $(this).find('Price').text();
                          $("#company").html(company);
                          $("#market").html(market);
                          $("#sector").html(sector);
                          $("#price").html(price);
                          });

                        }
                    });
                });
      </script>
   </head>

   <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
       <h2>List of Stocks:</h2>
      <div id="stockList"> 
          <ul><!--Temporary-->
              <li>BA</li>
              <li>CSCO</li>
              <li>ED</li>
              <li>GOOG</li>
              <li>MO</li>
          </ul><!--temp-->
      </div>
      <div id="stockInfo"> <!--Make a script to Show/Hide this div. Hide on default-->
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>1.</td><td>Company - </td><td id="company"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>2.</td><td>Market - </td><td id="market"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>3.</td><td>Sector - </td><td id="sector"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>4.</td><td>Price - </td><td id="price"></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

All I'm trying to do is display the XML data in the table i've provided. Outputting the Company's name, market, sector and share price in the their respective Table Cells (ex id="company"). The end result should look something like this:

1. Company - Google
2. Market - NASDAQ
3. Sector - Software
4. Price - $487.80

Instead all I'm getting is this:

1. Company -
2. Market -
3. Sector -
4. Price -

I have literally used the same loop dozens of times before (having only to modify variable names and what not) with great results. But now, for some odd reason, this script isn't working. What's funny is that I've copied and pasted the XML contents into another XML file in a different ASPX project and (of course with a little modification of the script variable names and what not) the XML data displayed just fine... It only seems to not work in this particular case which is extremely frustrating. I've re-done and re-wrote all of the XML, HTML and JavaScript involved nearly 4 times and yet, when I load the HTML page, I'm left staring at only what I hard coded in HTML, no XML data. It's like the script isn't even running.. This html file is located in a root folder, and the XML file I'm trying to grab data from is in a folder located in the root folder named "stylesheets". The File is named stocks.xml. Therefore the directory I have typed into the JavaScript is correct.

I just don't get it... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your success function being called with non-empty data in the _xml_ argument?  Also, do you have a sample of the xml you are trying to load?

Comment: Check the URL, as a relative path you may be trying to load it from a different location than you intended: "stylesheets/stocks.xml"

Comment: Put `console.log(xml)` after `success: function (xml) {` line, run the page, look into the console, get the logged value, post it here.

Comment: Here's my XML file in it's entirety 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<portfolio>
  <Stock>
    <Company>Google</Company>
    <Market>NASDAQ</Market>
    <Sector>Software</Sector>
    <Price>$487.80</Price>
  </Stock>
</portfolio>`

Console shows a JavaScript error (yellow) as "[19:15:33.190] ReferenceError: $ is not defined @ http://localhost:21953/stocks.aspx:18"

Comment: Have you made sure that your jquery script is being included in the page?  Maybe do a simple `$(document).ready(function () {alert('test');});` to see if it is working.

Comment: ^^I think you might have gotten it Nate. I realized that I didn't have my jQuery script in my directory nor did I have a script referencing it in the HTML. Did that real quick and the data displays wonderfully.. so stupid hahaha.. Thanks everyone